# Angularjs existing controller is undefined

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-controller

I'm building little bit bigger aplication in angular and I have problem with only one controller, they are all same, but this one is always undefined. Module is loaded because otherwise angular will crash.

My app structure looks like this...

```
angular.module("myAPP", [
 "ui.router",
 "ui.bootstrap",
 "ngSanitize",
 "ngAnimate",
 "templates",
 "factories",
 "filters",
 "myAPP.actions",
 "myAPP.users",
 "myAPP.pages",
 "myAPP.index",
 "myAPP.categories",
 "myAPP.packages",
 "myAPP.shops",
 "myAPP.stats" 
])
```

And child modules looks same:

```
angular.module("myAPP.actions",  [
 "myAPP.actions.detail",
 "myAPP.actions.new",
 "myAPP.actions.list",
 "myAPP.actions.edit"
])
.controller("ActionsCtrl",
(
 $scope,
 titleService
) ->
 titleService.setTitle "Actions"
)
```

And I'm getting

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ActionsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

So I try to invokeQueue

```
queue = angular.module("koukejakupuj.actions")._invokeQueue
console.log(queue)
```

and it looks like controller is loaded:

```
[Array[3]]
 0: Array[3]
  0: "$controllerProvider"
  1: "register"
  2: Arguments[2]
   0: "ActionsCtrl"
   1: function ($scope, titleService) {...
```

I cant figure out where could be problem.

//EDIT:
Code is in coffeescript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out after two days.

After refactoring I forget to remove file with controller with same name, pretty awful fail/error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
angular.module("myAPP.actions",  [
"myAPP.actions.detail",
"myAPP.actions.new",
"myAPP.actions.list",
"myAPP.actions.edit"
])
.controller("ActionsCtrl",function( $scope, titleService) {
// your controller code here.
}
);
```

Hope it helps.